# Is it still impossible to quarantine asymptomatic people in Portugal?

Tags: covid-19, public-health, portugal

News from [last year](https://www.portugalresident.com/portuguese-judges-who-queried-reliability-of-covid-tests-at-risk-of-being-disciplined/) was that an appeals court in Lisbon had ruled that it was illegal to quarantine people based solely on a (SARS-CoV-2) PCR test result. (Apparently, their ruling only applied outside the context of a State of Emergency.)

Have there been any legislative efforts to overrule this or some administrative/executive "workarounds"? Or is it still impossible to quarantine asymptomatic people in Portugal?

Comment: I edited out the part about you asking why you got a DV, since that should be asked on meta (though only if you get multiple DVs). If I was in your situation, I would likely flag for moderator attention, because you seem to be getting a DV very quickly after you post something, and it might be targeted voting)

Comment: 1 Hour and all this editing, a complaint & removal of body text over DVs, yet _no_ DVs (visible)? // Anyway. That a has court ruled: 'strictly illegal' doesn't remotely equal 'not being done'; ie: "impossible" seems quirky—part of 'new normal' (cat&mouse gaming?). May I suggest: 'still illegal' -~> or 'not being done' or sth like that? (Those are 2 totally different aspects, which _may_ overlap…)

Comment: @LаngLаngС: DV was probably retracted. It's possible after an edit...

Comment: Seems like a question that'd be better asked on Law.SE